# Setting a hotkey for an executables shortcut in .NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

I have the following code (based on the instructions at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773992(v=vs.85).aspx

```
Private Sub SetHotkey(FilePath As String)
    Const ssfPROGRAMS = 2            'Program Files

    Dim MyShell As Shell32.Shell = New Shell32.Shell
    Dim MyFolder As Shell32.Folder = MyShell.NameSpace(ssfPROGRAMS)

    If (MyFolder IsNot Nothing) Then
        Dim MyFolderItem As Shell32.FolderItem = MyFolder.ParseName(FilePath)
        If (MyFolderItem IsNot Nothing) Then
            Dim MyShellLink As ShellLinkObject = MyFolderItem.GetLink
            If (MyShellLink IsNot Nothing) Then
                MyShellLink.Hotkey = <<What goes here?>>
                MyShellLink.Save()
            End If
            MyShellLink = Nothing
        End If
        MyFolderItem = Nothing
    End If
End Sub
```

I am unsure which value to put as the Hotkey though. If for example I want to do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>. what value would I put? (I would think <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> is 6 but i don't know how to put in the character key).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says on linked page:

> The virtual keyboard shortcut is in the low-order byte, and the modifier flags are in the high-order byte. The modifier flags can be a combination of the following values.

Find your key in [Virtual-Key Codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx). This will go in the low order byte. In your example, <kbd>A</kbd> has value 0x41, or decimal 65.

For the upper order byte, the modifiers are <kbd>shift</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>alt</kbd>, and <kbd>extended</kbd>; equaling 1, 2, 4, and 8 respectively. Add up the values of the ones you want to use, in your case, <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> = 6. Then multiply this by 256 to shift it up one byte. This equals 1536.

Add 65 + 1536 = 1601. That is your hotkey for <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> +
 <kbd>A</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Here is how it goes

Based on [this page](https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=27473), I figured that there is some bit twiddling happening here.

For example

`(90 | (3 << 8))` returns 858 which is value of `CTRL + SHIFT + Z`

1. In the above part, 90 is ASCII value of "Z".
2. 3 is the value one gets by ORing 4 (for CTRL) with 1 (for SHIFT).
3. The value that we get in step 2 is left shift by 8
4. The value we get in step 3 is ORed with value in step 1

EDIT: The value for ALT is 4, CTRL is 2, SHIFT is 1

EDIT 2: For your example, the value for `CTRL+ALT+A` is (65 | (6 << 8)) which comes down to 1601.

Answer (score 1):

Another example:

```
MyShellLink.Hotkey = MakeWord(Keys.A, HotKeyModifiers.Control Or HotKeyModifiers.Alt)
```

Using:

```
Public Enum HotKeyModifiers
    Shift = 1
    Control = 2
    Alt = 4
    Extended = 8
End Enum

Public Function MakeWord(ByVal loByte As Byte, ByVal hiByte As Byte) As Short
    Return Convert.ToInt16(loByte Or (hiByte << 8))
End Function
```